# Same language multiple times under different stores

Tags: magento, translation, magento-1.9, categories, product

I'm facing the following problem: I'm going to setup a magento multisite installation with the following structure:

- DE

  - B2C

    - German
    - English
  - B2B

    - German
    - English
- CH

  - B2C

    - German
    - English
  - B2B

    - German
    - English

As you can see there will be two websites - one for german market the other for swiss market. Under that there will be two stores - one for consumer and one for business customers. So far so good. 
My problem are the four store views for each language, what would result in an extrem overhead while managing the translations for the not-default language - english in this case.

Is there any possibility to connect the english store view so that my customer would have to enter an english translation (for products or categories) only once an not four times?

Appriciate your ideas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see such an option to *connect the english store view*. You could probably let the customer translate one set of categories and products and write a little script that updates the other Store Views with the new translations after the customer finished.